# Scrapy. Создание сложных структур при парсинге (словарь в словаре)

Tags: парсер, scrapy

Допустим имеется несколько Item объектов, которые описывают свойства предмета

```html
import scrapy


class FullName(scrapy.Item):
    first = scrapy.Field()
    second = scrapy.Field()
    middle = scrapy.Field()

class Physical(scrapy.Item):
    growth = scrapy.Field()
    weight = scrapy.Field()
    hair = scrapy.Field()
```

И есть собственно Item, который принадлежит самому предмету. В него в качестве полей я хочу вставить Item'ы свойства объекта

```html
class Human(scrapy.Item):
    sex = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
    physical = <...Physical Item>
    full_name = <...FullName Item>
```

чтобы при экспорте данных получить структуру с указанной вложенностью

```
{
age: 23,
sex: male,
full_name: {first: test, second: test, middle: test}
physical: {growth: 90, height: 190, hair: blonde},
...
}
```

вложенность может быть любой глубины.

можно такое сделать средствами Scrapy? в доках Scrapy по [расширению item](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/items.html#extending-items) и [использованию загрузчиков](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/loaders.html), я не нашел подходящего функционала.

или я выбрал неподходящий инструмент и нужно делать вручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, Вам никто не запрещает не использовать Item объекты в прямом виде, а сделать в коде прямо вот так:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = (
        'http://icanhazip.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        full_name = dict()
        full_name['name'] = 'John'
        full_name['surname'] = 'Doe'

        physical = dict()
        physical['growth'] = 90
        physical['height'] = 190
        physical['hair'] = 'blonde'

        item = dict()
        item['age'] = 23
        item['sex'] = 'male'
        item['full_name'] = full_name
        item['physical'] = physical

        yield item
```

Что даст Вам в результате выполнения `scrapy crawl test -o test.json` вот такой прекрасный JSON:

```
[
{"age": 23, "sex": "male", "full_name": {"surname": "Doe", "name": "John"}, "physical": {"hair": "blonde", "growth": 90, "height": 190}}
]
```

Кроме того, насколько я думаю, ничто не помешает передать в Item словарь или список.
То есть, вот так тоже будет работать:

```
class Human(scrapy.Item):
    sex = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
    physical = scrapy.Field()
    full_name = scrapy.Field()

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = (
        'http://icanhazip.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Пропустим определения full_name и physical
        ...

        item = Human()
        item['age'] = 23
        item['sex'] = 'male'
        item['full_name'] = full_name
        item['physical'] = physical

        yield item
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал подобным образом, но у вас изящнее